# Minimum amount of parties containing round tables for everyone to meet each other

Tags: divide-and-conquer

So the problem is: There is a group of n people that want to meet each other and everyone is divided into pairs, so everyone has a partner that they know. Now there will be parties at which they can get to know each other. At every party there can be as many round tables as needed, at which people can sit. When they sit at the table, they get to know their left and right neighbour. What is the minimum amount of parties that need to be held for everyone to meet each other (except their own partner)?

It is assumed that n is a power of 2 in this case.

How could I start implementing such an algorithm? I've looked at the round robin tournament algorithm but this seems to be too different to be useful. I was thinking something along the lines of dividing the n people into groups so that everyone is in a seperate group from their partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n=2^k$.

Each person should get to know $2^k-1-1=2^k-2$ unknown people. At each party, each person get to know at most two unknown people. Hence, each person must join at least $\frac{2^k-2}2=2^{k-1}-1$ parties. So there must be at least that many parties.

---

The question is then whether that many parties are enough for all people to get to know each other. The answer is yes.

Let us divide and conquer, for $k\ge1$.

If $k=1$, no party is needed.

Assume $k\ge2$. Let us divide all people evenly into $2$ groups, keeping every pair of partners in the same group so that we have two groups of $2^{k-1}$ people each.

Suppose we have held $2^{(k-1)-1}-1=2^{k-2}-1$ parties for each group so that in each group, people know each other. We can consider those parties as $2^{k-2}-1$ parties for all $2^k$ people by holding two parties, one for each group together as one party for all $2^k$ people.

Our goal is to hold another $2^{k-2}$ parties so that everyone in one group get to know everyone in the other group.

Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{2^{k-1}}$ be the people in one group and $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{2^{k-1}}$ be the people in the other group. For $j$-th party, $1\le j\le 2^{k-2}$, we can arrange all people at one round table as follows:
$$a_1,b_{1+2j}, a_2, b_{2+2j},a_3, b_{3+2j},\cdots,a_{2^{k-1}}, b_{2^{k-1}+2j}$$
where $b_m$ means person $b_{m- 2^{k-1}}$ when $m>2^{k-1}$. Put it in another way, we can line up $a_1, a_2, a_3,\cdots, a_{2^{k-1}}$ as well as $b_1, b_2, b_3,\cdots, b_{2^{k-1}}$ first. Then interweave/zip two lines of people, starting with $a_1$ and $b_{1+2j}$.

You can verify the arrangements above let everyone in one group know everyone in the other group. Our goal is archived. So with $2^{k-2}-1+2^{k-2}=2^{k-1}-1$ parties, all people can get to know each other.